# Properly Join 3 Tables

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to fix a bug on my own to existing code not by me.Bug with this code is unless corresponding id has item in the 2nd table it wont show in output at all.In 1st table (mail) I have multiple entries and they get filtered out tho in output does show correct total number of mail ... just wont output it unless mail has item with in in 2nd table.
I have tried another query using diff joins

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    messageType, 
    sender, 
    mail.receiver, 
    subject, 
    body, 
    has_items, 
    money, 
    cod, 
    checked 
FROM 
    mail 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN mail_items 
            ON id = mail_id 
        LEFT JOIN item_instance 
            ON item_guid = guid
```

Problem with that is... I get error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1'

What can I do to make it so that both mail table and mail_items table join while it properly gets the item guid from 3rd table, and outputs mail table entries even if there no items for that mail in mail_items table.

```
//==========================$_GET and SECURE=================================
$start = (isset($_GET['start'])) ? $sqlc->quote_smart($_GET['start']) : 0;
if (is_numeric($start)); 
else 
    $start = 0;

$order_by = (isset($_GET['order_by'])) ? $sqlc->quote_smart($_GET['order_by']) : 'id';
if (preg_match('/^[_[:lower:]]{1,12}$/', $order_by)); 
else 
    $order_by = 'id';

$dir = (isset($_GET['dir'])) ? $sqlc->quote_smart($_GET['dir']) : 1;
if (preg_match('/^[01]{1}$/', $dir)); 
else 
    $dir = 1;

$order_dir = ($dir) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
$dir = ($dir) ? 0 : 1;
//==========================$_GET and SECURE end=============================

$query = $sql->query("SELECT a.id, a.messageType, a.sender, a.receiver, a.subject, a.body, a.has_items, a.money, a.cod, a.checked, b.item_guid, c.itemEntry
                      FROM mail a INNER JOIN mail_items b ON a.id = b.mail_id LEFT JOIN item_instance c ON b.item_guid = c.guid ORDER BY $order_by $order_dir LIMIT $start, $itemperpage");
$total_found = $sql->num_rows($query);
$this_page = $sql->num_rows($query);
$query_1 = $sql->query("SELECT count(*) FROM `mail`");
$all_record = $sql->result($query_1,0);
```

Comment: Can you post the schema of your tables?

Comment: The query you showed does not have "LIMIT 1" anywhere in it.  Therefore you're showing us the wrong query, or the wrong error.

Comment: The query is wrong as well. I think you tried to hurriedly copy-modify-paste the actual query from `$query = $sql->query(...)`

Comment: the schemas to big to post... ughhh.. .I had a feeling this too far fetched to ask here.. thanks anyway.

Comment: when I echo the query just says resource #25

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
/*
    The columns that you want to select
*/
FROM 
    mail a
LEFT OUTER JOIN mail_items b ON a.id = b.mail_id 
LEFT JOIN item_instance c ON b.item_guid = c.guid
```

Note, when you're trying to select your columns, make sure that you attach the proper table alias to the column name. Here the tables `mail`, `mail_items` and `item_instance` have `a`, `b`,`c` as their aliases respectively.

If you're using the above query keeping the same alias for the tables, you need to perform the following modification to your code:

```
$order_by = (isset($_GET['order_by'])) ? $sqlc->quote_smart($_GET['order_by']) : 'id';
if (preg_match('/^[_[:lower:]]{1,12}$/', $order_by)); 
else 
    $order_by = 'a.id';
```

Comment: gives me error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: can you post the query that you're executing? where does `LIMIT 1` come from?

Comment: guess from $start variable above.. tho it says 0

Comment: @ChristopherSebastiano: Can you try either of the two things and test: 1. remove `ORDER BY $order_by $order_dir` from your `$sql->query("...")` OR 2. modify your else statement above as `$order_by = 'a.id';` (*As I said, you need to provide the correct table alias for your query to work*).

Comment: not working :/ .. i attached screenshots somewhere on here .. (new to site)

Comment: idk if it helps but the full code is here:
https://github.com/Amit86/minimanager/blob/master/mail_on.php

that is repo I got it from

Comment: @ChristopherSebastiano: errm...can you try with removing the `LIMIT $start, $itemperpage` and try? I might've a hunch :)

Comment: I don't see any assignment to `$itemperpage` anywhere in the code. That will cause this error.

Comment: @Barmar: That was my hunch as well :)

Comment: still same error :(((
$itemperpage is global variable from config page

Comment: @ChristopherSebastiano: Can you print the query for us? The one that's getting executed after all the substitution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a SQL guru but I think

```
FROM mail a INNER JOIN mail_items b
```

needs the `AS` keyword for alias assignment:

```
FROM mail AS a INNER JOIN mail_items AS b
```

Comment: AFAIK `AS` is optional when you're providing an alias name for a table.

Comment: here screenshots that may help give idea of tables
http://i47.tinypic.com/2q1avyh.png
http://i48.tinypic.com/sw72qa.png
http://i45.tinypic.com/1sczsm.png
http://i50.tinypic.com/2lcptvl.png
http://i48.tinypic.com/242fmsx.png

Comment: This solution is only showing entries that have an Item.. need it to show mails without and with items

Comment: But this is a SQL syntax error, it has nothing to do with improper joins - that would simply return incorrect data sets. Focus on the query itself not the schema.

Answer (score 0):

try this type,
**select * from table1 as T1 join table2 as T2 on T.id=T2.id join table3 as T3 on T2.id=T3.id**

Comment: The OP's question was how to show data when the table `T2` (*in your case*) does not have any data corresponding to the id in table `T1`. A `join` as you specified will not solve the issue he's facing.

Comment: The  1st answer is right query as shown here
http://i47.tinypic.com/2qwht75.png
but in php it throws syntax error :/